# Front end vibration

Tags: chevrolet, vibration, trailblazer

My 02 trailblazer has a loud vibration in front end and it gets worse when air conditioner is on. Took it to a garage and they just said it's in the engine, I don't want them to tear into my engine on a fishing expedition. Runs good, uses no oil, everything works on it. I need help, any suggestion

Comment: Maybe the harmonic balancer? It's tough to say without seeing/hearing the engine. If you remove the belt does the issue persist?

Comment: The harmonic balancer is the first place I would look.

Comment: I've taken the belt off and it still had the vibration